# AWS S3 and Spring 3.1.0-Release in java 1.8 project

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

getting the below error when i try to implement upload/download files to AWS S3 in a java and spring project - with old version of Spring which is 3.1.0-release and java is 1.8.
i dont want to ugrade the version of spring as it widely used in the application so is there any way to achieve this with out uprgrading spring version.
your help would be appreciated. - please see the error below.

Thanks.

ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file ....**[C:\Workspace\se\seyaWEB\target\classes\com\add\web\helper\S3Config.class]**; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13568

Comment: I assume you would expect from us to know what exactly is in this file `C:\Workspace\se\seyaWEB\target\classes\com\add\web\helper\S3Config.class`

Comment: i do have three bean definitions S3Client,S3Presigner and S3TransferManager - i dont have any thing else - below is the bean definition for S3client

Comment: `@Bean
public S3Client s3Client() { 
AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKeyId, secretKeyId));
return S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).region(Region.US_WEST_1).build();
 }`

Comment: any idea on this please?

Comment: Spring version has been upgraded !! S3client had some implementation of the java 8 features which  is not supported by spring 3 !! issue resolved.